# How do I implement Moga Controller support in my Java libgdx game?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, keymapping, gamepad

How do I implement Moga Controller support in my Java libgdx game?

I am working on a libgdx game and I want to implement moga pocket and game pad support

If I understand correctly, mode a on moga controllers acts as moga pocket style support and mode b is like game pad support

how do I get input from both modes and also detect if the moga/gamepad controller is even there

If mode b on moga controllers is the same thing as an Xbox controller, then please tell me because I already know how to add Xbox controller support and then I'll only want to know how to add mode a/moga pocket support

Comment: I'm familiar with libgdx, but not so much with Moga Controllers. Have you tried looking at their documentation? I quickly visited their site and they have implementation demos and code examples for their SDK. I'm guessing you might have to implement it separate from the libgdx API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(" I'm familiar with libgdx, but not so much with Moga Controllers. Have you tried looking at their documentation? I quickly visited their site and they have implementation demos and code examples for their SDK. I'm guessing you might have to implement it separate from the libgdx API. ")

Thanks, I looked at the website : http://www.mogaanywhere.com/developers/download-page/         the website had all the answers and things I needed to implement it into my game